# my pfsense is reducing the speed to 40 mbps from 300+ mbps, what can be the issue?

Tags: network, speed, pfsense

I have a pfsense system BUSINESS B100 - CELERON DUAL CORE J1800 2.41GHZ 4GB DDR3 SODIMM SSD 60GB HDMI. https://www.amazon.com.br/gp/product/B086M2D8DJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I selected the speed for both interfaces:

[image]

If I bypass the pfsense using the same USB LAN ether my speed is 300+, go back to the pfsense and it goes down to ~40.

[image]

I have disabled most all advanced features like snort and pfBlockerNG and in the advanced/networking have all checked to disable offloading.

On my DGS-1024C all link lights are green indicating 1000 speed.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad to answer as asked. Please edit the question to include a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations, including the pfSense configuration.

Comment: Celeron J1800 is a (Silvermont) Atom CPU - not all too beefy for various workloads. Also, a USB NIC is generally badly suited for a router/firewall.